# Does a file operation (move, rename) change last modified field of a file?

Tags: android, file, filesystems, file-rename, file-move

What does "`lastmodified`" describe? Just the file's content or also file system related things like `file name` and `Path`?

My interest goes especially for the **Android platform**. I will store data in my **app's directory**. A quick test showed, that a **Samsung Android device** with Android 4.2.2 does not change the date when moving files with the build in file browser.

Comment: Move and rename are not file changes (file data is not altered). Why would Last Modified be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my experience it doesnt change it. After such operations I manually do

```
file.setLastModified(System.currentTimeMillis());
```